# How to show convexity of an inequality?

Tags: convex-analysis

How would $x^2 + y^4 + z^2 < 5$ be shown to be convex? What I was thinking was that this is sort of like an ellipsoid and these are convex sets. The traditional definition of convexity for some $\lambda \in [0,1]$ such that a convex combination is also in the set does not seem clear here because how would we consider that against the "<5" part?

Comment: Show that if $x^2+y^4+z^2 < 5$ and $a^2+b^4+c^2 < 5$ then $(ta+(1-t)x)^2+(tb+(1-t)y)^4+(tc+(1-t)z)^2 < 5$ for $0 < t < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The functions $\pi_k: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi_k(x) = x_k^m$ are convex for $m$ even and positive. As Robert points out in the comments, the sum of convex functions is convex. Hence $(x,y,z) = x^2+y^4+z^2$ is convex.

If $f$ is convex, then the set $\{x | f(x) < L \}$ is easily shown to be convex.

In your example, $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^4+z^2$, $L=5$.

Comment: A key point here is that the sum of convex functions is convex.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Thanks for catching that omission.

Answer (score 1):

Given the specific wording of your question, you seem to be confusing the convexity of *sets* and the convexity of *functions*, or perhaps what it means for an inequality to be convex.

When presented with an equation or inequality along with a claim that it is "convex", what is meant is that the points that satisfy that equation/inequality form a convex set. Similarly, a system of equations and inequalities (collectively called *constraints*) is called "convex" if the points that satisfy all of the constraints simultaneously form a convex set.

A set $X$ is convex if the set contains every line segment that spans any two points in the set:
$$\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha) x_2\in X \quad \forall x_1,x_2\in X,~\alpha\in[0,1]$$
Mapped to your example, if $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ both satisfy the inequality, then so must every point in the segment between them:
$$(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2)^2+(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2)^2+(\alpha z_1+(1-\alpha)z_2)^2<5 \quad \forall \alpha\in[0,1]$$

A function $f$ is convex if its domain is a convex set, and if every secant line lies above the function itself:
$$\alpha f(x_1+(1-\alpha) x_2\in X) \leq \alpha f(x_1) + (1-\alpha) f(x_2) \quad \forall x_1,x_2\in\mathop{\textrm{dom}} f,~\alpha\in[0,1]$$

Not surprisingly, the notions of convexity for sets and functions are tightly related: a function is convex if and only if its epigraph is a convex set:
$$ f~\text{is convex} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\mathop{\textrm{epi}} f \triangleq \left\{ (x,y) ~\middle|~ x\in\mathop{\textrm{dom}} f,~f(x)\leq y \right\}~\text{is convex}$$

With regards to your specific example, copper.hat's post is on point. For an convex function $f$, the constraint $f(x) \leq y$ describes a convex set, whether $y$ is a constant or another variable.